# Cannot install Jupyterlab Cannot uninstall 'six'

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

im trying to install jupyterlab using pip install jupyterlab
but im getting this error

```
Found existing installation: six 1.10.0 ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: You can use the flag [`--ignore-installed`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-I) with your `pip` command. To ignore the already installed `six` library: `pip install jupyterlab --ignore-installed six`

Comment: @Alex like this 'pip install jupyterlab --ignore-installed six' ?

Comment: Yep, see my updated comment

Comment: @Alex Thank you, im not having any errors now.

Comment: Are you trying to install JupyterLab into the global environment? I would highly recommend using a virtual environment instead.